What year is my Gary Fisher Tassajara mountain bike
The numbers I found underneath the bottom bracket shell are:
WTU1082383M (serial number)
332M
BI-M23 (although, might be B1 and/or 1123)

Thanks

Is this a matter of curiosity or is there other information you’d like to have and you think that knowing the year will help you find it?

Do you have photos of the bike? The numbers you found on it are very little use, as there is no registration office for frame numbers.

@Willeke WTU is a Trek frame number and Trek can identify the bike from this. Some Trek dealers can use the Trek Warranty website (Dexter) to identify most models from this number.

Could you add clean and clear photos of both sides of the bike?  Use [edit] and that should trigger a re-open.    Something like this   https://www.reddit.com/r/xbiking/comments/15ffdf6/picked_up_this_old_gary_fisher_tassajara/

I'm just curious when we bought it.  Probably 93-96 range.  Trek said it was to old to have the SN in their database.

Oh, it is an early one! Trek acquired Gary Fisher (both the man and the brand) in 1993. So it can't be any older than that. But many quality bikes were using V-brakes by 1994/5. Take a photo of the derailleur and cranks from the other side, we'll get a model year for you.

Based on the shape of the cranks (shimano "A") and the yellow branding, I'm calling 1995.

Aside - eyeballing, the front fork looks to be bent back a little.  Has it been in a hard stop or collision ?

@Criggie i think it's a trick of your eyes

Thanks everyone

Your bike is in the 1997 catalogue.
https://www.retrobike.co.uk/gallery2/v/Manufacturer+Archive/Gary/Catalogues/Gary+Fisher+Catalogue+1997.pdf.html
Yours is the Ballistic Blue colourway, not the red pictured.
This would probably have been available from Autumn 1996 (new model year).

